# how to detect existence of large file in iOS?

Tags: ios, nsfilemanager

At runtime, my app downloads some large video files and plays them.  They are large, so I figure they might get wiped at any time by the system trying to recover memory.

I had trouble using `[fileManager fileExistsAtPath: pathOfVideo]`:

Then I found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2457782/194309) saying we should *not* use `-fileExistsAtPath` to determine if files exist.

The suggested solution is to *open* the file and see if it fails on opening.  Even for 30MB files?  I'm not so worried about race conditions here; the files are downloaded from the server and played in MediaPlayer.  Should I still open the 30MB file to see if it exists instead of using fileExistsAtPath?

Comment: (for the record, my problem was with directory permissions, but the question about large file detection remains answerable..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you follow the links to the discussion of why one is advised not to use `fileExistsAtPath` (see [Race Conditions and Secure File Operations](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/SecureCodingGuide/Articles/RaceConditions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002585)), given the sandboxing of iPhone apps, it might be an acceptable risk.

Answer (score 1):

May be this will help you

```
NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [fileManager fileAttributesAtPath:filePath traverseLink:YES];
    if(fileAttributes != nil)
    {
        NSString *fileSize = [fileAttributes objectForKey:NSFileSize];
    enter code here

        NSLog(@"File size: %@ kb", fileSize);
    }
```

Comment: could be nice, but xcode says 'fileAttributesAtPath:traverseLink:' is deprecated

Comment: check this http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/attributesOfItemAtPath:error:

Comment: Try `attributesOfItemAtPath:error:`, as suggested by the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

If race conditions aren't a concern use fileExistsAtPath. What was the permissions issue on iOS device?

Comment: ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0 was 700 so I changed it to 755 to match the rest of its parents and children.